# Programmatic access to iOS video app audio input

Tags: ios, audio, video-processing, externalinterface

I’m developing an app that will need to supply an external audio input to the video camera app in iOS. Is it possible to get access to the audio input of the camera app programatically from another app so the audio output from my audio app appears as an audio input option for the iOS video recorder?

Comment: this sounds like either the app has a way to let you choose the audio source for recording (then it's a general computer usage problem), or you'd have to pry the app open (decompile it)... -- so you want to create a "software" audio source on your system? now *that* sounds like an interesting API question. if so, perhaps [edit] your question and rephrase, especially the title, so people know you aren't asking about that app, but about creating a virtual audio source (like a microphone but your own program creates the audio)

Comment: look for "virtual audio cable" or "virtual audio device".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.